# C++ Laplace expansion

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program to find the determinant of a matrix n x n, using Laplace expansion.

Briefly, the program creates a two-dimensional array based on a user request. The users choose the size of the two-dimensional array and fills it in themselves. Next comes the computation of the matrix using Laplace.

The problem is that I can't use the resulting array values in the determinant function. I'm completely new to C ++, so any help would be welcome. The code shown below. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

void fin(int**, int, int);
void fout(int**, int, int);

int main() {
   int **board, n;
   double alpha, beta;
   cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns: ";
   cin >> n;
   cout << endl;
   
   board = new int* [n];
   for(int row = 0; row < n; row++)
       board[row] = new int[n];
   
   fin(board,n,n);
   cout << endl;
   fout(board,n,n);
   cout << endl;
   
   cout << "Determinant of the matrix is " << determinant(board, n);
    cout << endl;
   return 0;
}

void fin(int **p, int R, int C)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < R; row++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << C + 1 << " numbers for row number " << R + 1 << ": ";
        for(int col = 0; col < C; col++)
            cin >> p[row][col];
        cout << endl;
        
    }
}

void fout(int **p, int R, int C)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < R; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < C; col++)
            cout << setw(5) << p[row][col];
        cout << endl;
        
    }
}

int determinant( int **result, int n) {
   int det = 0;
   int submatrix[10][10];
   if (n == 2)
   return ((result[0][0] * result[1][1]) - (result[1][0] * result[0][1]));
   else {
      for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
         int subi = 0;
         for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            int subj = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
               if (j == x)
               continue;
               submatrix[subi][subj] = result[i][j];
               subj++;
            }
            subi++;
         }
         det = det + (pow(-1, x) * result[0][x] * determinant( submatrix, n - 1 ));
      }
   }
   return det;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the forward declaration of `determinant`. Add `int determinant( int **result, int n);` up where you declare `fin` and `fout`. Alternately you could put `main` at the bottom of the code after the functions have been defined because a definition also counts as a declaration.

Comment: Unrelated: look into [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as a replacement for the [raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/raw-pointers?view=vs-2019) dynamic arrays if permitted. Heck, even if you're not allowed to use it, look into `vector` anyway and put it in the toolbox for later. One of the handiest tools in C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement the Laplace expansion algorithm in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121487/how-do-i-implement-the-laplace-expansion-algorithm-in-c)